# InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression could not be translated. - Seemly caused by MaxBy (Or OrderByDescending.Take(1)/.First()

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have a query to get records based on a latest date throwing the exception listed in the title:

```
            var thisResult = ctx.Table1
                .Join(ctx.Table2,
                    t1 => t1.recordId.Substring(0, 13),
                    t2 => t2.recordId.Substring(0, 13),
                    (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
                .SelectMany(t1t2 => t1t2.t1.ICollectionNavigationProperty,
                    (t1t2, cnp) => new { t1t2, cnp})
                .Where(t1t2cnp=> !t1t2cnp.cnp.nullableIntProperty.Equals(null))
                .GroupBy(t1t2cnp => t1t2cnp.cnp.nullableIntProperty)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    UniqueNullableIntProperty = g.Key,
                    bulkOfStuff = g.MaxBy(x => x.t1t2.t2.NullableDateTime)
                }).ToList();
```

If I remove the MaxBy it works fine. If I do the ToList into memory and then do a MaxBy it works as well. But doing the ToList into memory brings back 5000 - 6000 records and I'm not going to do that. Also tried .OrderByDescending.Take(1) / .OrderByDescending.First() and got same results. What can I do to solve this?